# Android ExpandableListView item images disappear

Tags: android, listview, imageview, expandablelistview

I have to display a list of football players in a list. No problem about that, everything works fine but the little flags for the nationality are disappearing while I scroll down my list.

Here is what it should look like : [list item player OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZ2Bg.png)
And here is the result I have after some scrolling : [list item player NOK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJSlC.png)

I also have an Image for the portrait of the player and another one to show the shirt which are working fine.

Here is some part of my code (I only put some parts of it to reduce the size and to put away what's working but feel free to ask for more if you need) :

My item list layout (partial layout, you won't get the same result as the image show) :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/portrait"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/portrait_default" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/nationalityLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logoNationality"
            android:layout_width="13dp"
            android:layout_height="13dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nationality"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="13dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/shirt"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have a holder for my items :

```
private class ChildViewHolder {
    public ImageView portrait;
    public ImageView logoNationality;
    public TextView nationality;
    public LinearLayout nationalityLayout;
    public LinearLayout shirt;
    public TextView number;

    public void reset() {
        portrait.setImageBitmap(null);
        portrait.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.portrait_default);
        nationalityLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        nationality.setText("");
        number.setText("");
    }
}
```

And the getChildView from my adapter (with flags being a map filled while putting items in the adapter list and playerShirt a BitmapDrawable loaded before) :

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ChildViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.liste_item, null);
        holder = new ChildViewHolder();
        holder.portrait = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.portrait);
        holder.nationalityLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nationalityLayout);
        holder.logoNationality = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.logoNationality);
        holder.nationality = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nationality);
        holder.shirt= (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.shirt);
        holder.number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.number);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ChildViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.reset();
    }

    FootPlayer player = children.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);

    // Doing nothing with portrait for now
    if (player.getNationality() != null) {
        holder.nationalityLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.nationality.setText(player.getNationality());
        if (player.getNatImg() != null) {
            holder.logoNationality.setImageDrawable(flags.get(player.getNatImg()));
        } else {
            holder.logoNationality.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    } else {
        holder.nationalityLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    holder.shirt.setBackgroundDrawable(playerShirt);
    holder.number.setText(String.valueOf(player.getNumber()));

    return convertView;
}
```

Right now, flags are appearing at the beginning of the list, proving me that the flags map is correctly filled with my images, but while I scroll down they start to disappear randomly and in the end none of them show up anymore.

So important points are :

- My flags map is correctly filled with BitmapDrawable (and correct keys)
- My playerShirt is also a BitmapDrawable but doesn't disappear as flags do
- I already tried to use setBitmapImage instead of setBitmapDrawable to set the flag image (and also set the background as I'm currently doing with the shirt)
- I tried with drawable res images and I have the same result
- I know that I go through my if condition to show the flag correctly

Any help about this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting `logoNationality` visibility back to `VISIBLE`, as you are doing with `nationalityLayout`. So I guess once it's gone for the first time, it remains invisible, even if you later reuse the view setting a drawable to it.

Have a look to the fixed code:

```
if (player.getNationality() != null) {
    holder.nationalityLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // <- SET VISIBLE, Well done!
    holder.nationality.setText(player.getNationality());

    holder.logoNationality.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // <- Missing line: SET VISIBLE as before.
    if (player.getNatImg() != null) {
       holder.logoNationality.setImageDrawable(flags.get(player.getNatImg()));
    } else {
        holder.logoNationality.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  // <- OK, no logo, so hide it.
    }
} else {
    holder.nationalityLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); // No nationality, hides entire layout.
}
```

Comment: Meh. I'm so blind. Thanks a lot!